# assert_response doesn't work with webrat in selenium mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, integration-testing, webrat

Anyone know how to get assert_response to work with webrat using selenium?  I keep getting

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `response_code' for nil:NilClass
```

Here's my test:

```
def test_basic_page_load
  visit root_path
  click_link "register"
  assert_response 200
end
```

Here's the error:

```
==> Waiting for Selenium RC server on port 4444... Ready!
==> Waiting for rails application server on port 3001... Ready!
E

  1) Error:
test_basic_page_load(UserCrudTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `response_code' for nil:NilClass
    /test/integration/user_crud_test.rb:11:in `test_basic_page_load'

Finished in 12.269964 seconds.
```

I'm sure it's something silly that I'm missing, but I just don't see it.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, it looks like it's not possible at the moment.

The testing process starts a new mongrel instance from the command line (in `Webrat::Selenium::ApplicationServers::Rails`) and therefore doesn't have access to the `@controller` variable that would be set by `ActionController::Integration::Session.get`.  This `@controller` variable is used by assert_response.

I wonder how much work it would be to start up a mongrel server using `fork` instead of `system` (in `Webrat::Selenium::ApplicationServers::Rails.start`).  It could maybe be combined with `selenium.wait_for_page_to_load` to ensure the test waits for the server process to finish the response.  Just an idea, I probably won't look into it any more.

For anyone using webrat with shoulda, something like this will still work:

```
setup do
  fill_in :login, :with => Factory.next(:login)
  fill_in :email, :with => Factory.next(:email)
  fill_in "Password", :with => 'asdf'
  fill_in "Password confirmation", :with => 'asdf'
  click_button :Register
  selenium.wait_for_page_to_load(10)
end
should_create :user
```

Cheers,
Brian